# Fixing SQL Query so it will become more Efficient

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got 3 tables:

1. `mobile_users` - with `id`,`phone_type`,...

2+3. `iphone_purchases` AND `android_purchases` - with `id`,`status`,`user_id`,..

I am trying to get all of the users who made  2 or more purchases.
successful purchase is identified by `status > 0`.
Also I am tring to get the total amount of users in the `mobile_users` table in the same query.

this is the query I came up with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `users`,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM `mobile_users`
       ) AS `total`
  FROM `mobile_users` 
 WHERE `mobile_users`.`phone_type` = 'iphone'
   AND ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM ( SELECT `status`,
                         `user_id` 
                    FROM `iphone_purchases`
                  UNION
                  SELECT `status`,
                         `user_id` 
                    FROM `android_purchases`
                ) AS `purchase_list` 
          WHERE `purchase_list`.`status` > 0 
            AND `purchase_list`.`user_id` = `mobile_users`.`id`
       ) >= 2
```

It's very slow, and I have to find a way to improve it.
Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
Also you should take in consideration that i'm building this query with sub-queries in PHP. 
I'm building it with more conditions on the WHERE statment.

Comment: Why store iphone/android purchases in separate tables?

Comment: Select the total number of iphone users with 2 or more iphone+android purchases and display this number next to the total number of users.... Can an iphone user even appear in the android_purchases database?

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is just returning counts of users, not each user.

The following restructures your query.  It counts the number of purchases for iphones and androids separately, and then combines them using `left outer join`.  The `where` clause simply combines the counts:

```
select mu.*, i.cnt as iphones, a.cnt as androids
from mobile_users mu left outer join
     (SELECT `user_id`, count(*) as cnt
      FROM `iphone_purchases`
      where `status` > 0
      group by user_id
     ) i
     on i.user_id = mu.id left outer join
     (SELECT `user_id`, count(*) as cnt
      FROM `android_purchases`
      where `status` > 0
      group by user_id
     ) a
     on a.user_id = mu.id
where coalesce(i.cnt, 0) + coalesce(a.cnt, 0) >= 2;
```

Comment: Does coalesce(i.cnt, 0) return the cnt if it's non null, otherwise 0? Would it be appropriate to coalesce in the column list too?

Comment: @JustinDanielson . . . `coalesce()` returns the second argument if the first is `NULL` (and it can take more than two arguments).  As for the `select` . .  yes, it makes sense to do it there too, if you would rather see `0` than `NULL`.